# Angular 5 - The "verify that it is part of this module" message

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm having an error after change my component from the `app.component.html` to another `other-component.html`

**app.component.html** (this works well)

```
<main>
  <my-component></my-component>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

BUT, in this way...

**app.component.html**

```
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

**other.component.html** (this fails)

```
<section>
    Something here
    and my-component here: <my-component></my-component>
</section>
```

Got the error:

> 1. If 'my-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'my-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.

I'm using the "child component lazy loading" on my router.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule             } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'first-module',
    loadChildren: 'app/first-module/first-module.module#FirstModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And this is my `app.module.ts` which loads `core.module` (I have `my-component` inside the core.module btw)

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRoutes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**core.module**

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

import { MyComponent} from './components/my-component/my-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe
  ],
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {

  constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

 }
```

So, the app starts when y go to the url localhost:4200/first-component and it loads the main app.module which loads core module and this last one loads my-component. But it seems that only works if I put my-component on the app.component.html.

Can anyone give me some help on this?

Comment: Assuming the "other" component is in the "first" module, then since it uses MyComponent, then MyComponent should also be declared in the "first" module. Your CoreModule should probably not contain components. Only singleton services.

Comment: If you use "my-component" in any component declared in a module, which doesnt import the module where "my-component" was declared and exported, will fail

Comment: @JBNizet "other" component is on "core" module, since the "app.module" loads "core" module, the component associated to it should be loaded to. It's working but only in the context of the app.component.html not in others.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo "core.module" is the module were "my-component" was declared and exported. I've imported the core.module on my app.module so it's already done. If I import the "core module" on my "first module", the console prints:  "Error: CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only "

Comment: Yup, thats because of the restriction that you imposed in the core module, that can only be imported once (normally by the app module). The fact that a component which is used across many modules is declared/exported in the core module, is a wrong design decision on your side

Comment: @Jota.Toledo if there is a set of component (common components) that you want share between all your application and make them load at the first time, then yo make them part of a module (core.module) or maybe you can call it shared.module. Am I wrong?

Comment: Such components belong in a shared module, that is correct. A shared module should by definition be imported by all your modules. On the other hand, core module can only be imported once by the root module.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo yeah that totally make sense.